# Using the ArrayAdapter class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

Method-1: ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)

Method-2: ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)

I was using the array adapter class by passing values through method 2, and then I experimented a bit and passed values by method 1 and it still worked.
I could not find a difference between the two.

Can anybody help me out...i.e do i have to have to pass a TextViewResourceId?

Comment: ... and what documentation is saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use method 2 if the id of your text view isn't the default id.  If it is, then using method 1 is perfectly fine.

As a style thing I prefer to use method 2 at all times though, just to be clear about what the id is so a maintainer doesn't need to remember it or look it up.

Comment: What do you mean by a default id?